# Memory leak for uiimage

Tags: iphone

I'm getting heavy leak in UIImage. Could you please help me?

```
-(UIImage*)getImage{
  return [self getForrrrImage];
}

-(UIImage*)getForrrrImage{
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  UIImage *imageResult=nil;
  if(index>=0 && index<[imagesPatchs count]){
    NSString *key=[imagesPatchs objectAtIndex:index];
    if(small)
      imageResult=[savedImagesDic objectForKey:key];

    if(!imageResult){
      NSRange range=[key rangeOfString:@"test_bg"];
      if(range.location!=NSNotFound){
        NSString *filePath1;
        if(small){
          NSString *str=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@_small",key];
          filePath1=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:str ofType:@"jpg"];
          [str release];
        }
        else
          filePath1=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:key ofType:@"jpg"];
        if(filePath1){
          imageResult=[self createImageFromFile:filePath1];
          if(small){
            [savedImagesDic setObject:imageResult forKey:key];

          }
        }
      }

      else{

        NSString *filePath;
        if(small)
          filePath=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@/%@_small.png", DOCUMENTS_FOLDER, key];
        else
          filePath=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@/%@.png", DOCUMENTS_FOLDER, key];

        if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]){
          imageResult=[self createImageFromFile:filePath];
          if(small){
            if(imageResult){
              [savedImagesDic setObject:imageResult forKey:key];
              [imageResult release];
            }
            else {
              imageResult=[UIImage alloc];
            }

          }
          else{
            if(!imageResult)
              imageResult=[UIImage alloc];

          }
        }

        [filePath release];
      }
    }
  }
  else
    imageResult=[UIImage alloc];
  [pool drain];

  return imageResult;
} 

-(UIImage*)createImageFromFile:(NSString*)filePath{

  NSAutoreleasePool *pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  UIImage *imageResult=nil;
  NSData *data=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:NSUncachedRead error:nil];
  imageResult=[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data] ;  ----->Heavy memory leak

  [data release];
  [pool drain];
  return imageResult;  

}
```

Comment: getForrrrImage <-- any special meaning for so many rrrrrrr ?

Comment: It's grrrrrrreat?  Might as well guess.

Comment: why you need to write NSAutoreleasePool *pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; in every function ???

Comment: No..but i am still searching 4 my answer...plz help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
[[UIImage alloc] initWithData: data];
```

You might try

```
[UIImage imageWithData: data];
```

This would make sure that you do not need to care about releasing the object because you use the class method which initializes the Image for you already.

And then you should also shoot for autoreleases. Like

```
[[[UIImage alloc] initWithData: data] autorelease]
```

Just as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you're returning a mess of autoreleased and retained objects, depending on the code path taken. Here's how to fix that:

First, in your `createImageFromFile:` you need to do `return [imageResult autorelease];` and remove the `[imageResult release];` from your `getForrrrImage` method.

Next, you have a lot of `imageResult=[UIImage alloc];` which is wrong since you're allocating but not initializing the object. Also you don't autorelease it. If you don't have an image, then simply return `nil` instead.

Remember: you always should return autoreleased objects, *except* if:

- your method starts with `new`
- your method starts with `alloc`
- your method contains the word `copy` (as in `mutableCopy`)

In all other cases it is expected that non-owning (i.e. autoreleased) objects are returned. While until now sticking to this was merely to make your life easier (and that of everyone who works with your code), sticking to these conventions is enforced when using the Automatic Reference Counting of iOS 5. So you want to make sure your code does follow these rules unless you love lots of debugging and refactoring later on.

I also think your use of autorelease pools is overkill and you should remove them (except if you actually debugged and measured and found that they are necessary to prevent a memory warning). Anyway, if you want to stick to them, your will need to do this to save your object from getting deallocated before you return it:

```
[imageResult retain];
[pool drain];
[imageResult autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go through every `createImageFromFile` and make sure you release afterwards, cause you don't.

Second, you should use NSString's convenience methods like [NSString stringWithFormat], then you don't have to alloc an NString every time. Will save you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You have alloced `imageResult` in `getForrrrImage` and `createImageFromFile` and returned that for which there is no matching release. If you need to return an alloced object from a method then send it an autorelease message.

```
MyObject *obj = [[MyObject alloc] init];
return [obj autorelease];
```

Note that you can't release `obj` in the method as you need that object in the caller. That's why autorelease is used. You can retain the returned autoreleased `obj` in the caller if you need that in future.

Comment: hey i used [imageResult autorelease].but its giving crash

Comment: You may need to retain the returned object. Please go through memory management programming guide (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html). Few hours in reading this might save your hundreds of hours.